# Qt QML: Get reference to object emitting a signal

Tags: qt, qml

I have a screen with some rectangles which can contain text. The text content of these rectangles should be allowed to change through clicking on buttons in the screen where this component is used. The problem I am having is how to know in the screen which uses this component which instance is selected. I thought about solving this via emitting a signal, which transmits the id of the instance as reference, but it seems this does not work. How could this be accomplished? Here my custom rectangle component

```
Rectangle {
     id: root
     width: 50
     height: 50
     color: "#000000"
     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
     border.color: "#555555"
     property int value: 0
     signal sendId(Item)

Text {
    id: displayed_text
    color: "#ffffff"
    text: root.value
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    font.pixelSize: 15
}

MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        root.border.color="#222222"
        root.sendId(root.id)

    }

}
```

}

and here the file where other buttons should change the content of the custom component:

```
            property Item selected: myRectangle
            function changeSelected(value) {
                selected.value=5
            }
            function setSelected(it) {
                root.selected=it
            }

            MyRectangle {
                id: myRectangle
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    myRectangle.sendId.connect(tempNumber.setSelected)
                }
            }
            MyRectangle {
                id: myRectangle1
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    myRectangle1.sendId.connect(tempNumber.setSelected)
                }
            }
            MyRectangle {
                id: myRectangle2
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    myRectangle2.sendId.connect(tempNumber.setSelected)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root.sendId(root.id)
```

The `id` is not a regular property. Don't use it as such. The purpose of the `id` is to get you a reference, with which you can refer to a particular object, so all you really need is:

```
root.sendId(root)
```

And if `root` is your qml file root object, `sendId(root)` would work too as long as `sendId` is not shadowed, root members can be referenced directly, keep in mind this only applies to the root object, it won't work for a object that is a direct or indirect parent but not root.

It is recomended practice to abstain from giving everything an `id` - only use ids when you really need to reference a particular object and no other way exists.

Another thing you are missing is that unlike JS functions, you do have to provide some typing for a signal. You can still use `var` and pass anything, but usually it is more efficient to narrow down the scope. So you need type and identifier:

```
signal sendId(Item item)
```

This way you can access `item` in the signal handlers, so you can avoid the awkward imperative connection syntax, so instead you can simply:

```
        MyRectangle {               
            onSendId: tempNumber.setSelected(item)
        }
```

However, I'd say your design is not optional. Signals are supposed to be employed when you aim for generality and reuse. Your usage scenario is more specific, thus the usage of signals can be avoided altogether:

```
// Rect.qml
Rectangle {
  width: 50
  height: 50
  color: manager.selected === this ? "red" : "blue"
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: manager.selected = parent
  }
}

// main.qml
Window {
  id: manager

  visible: true
  width: 600
  height: 300

  property Item selected: null

  Row {
    spacing: 2
    Repeater {
      model: 10
      delegate: Rect {}
    }
  }
}
```

As the following example shows, you can directly access objects by id as long as they can be found down the object tree. The same applies to properties, however while the `id` will work for any object down the tree, properties will only work if they are declared in the root object of the particular qml file.